# Series calculation about 1/a + 1/(a+b) + 1/(a+2b) + 1/(a+3b) + ... + 1/(a+k*b)

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, scientific-computing

Is there an efficient way to calculate the following series without loop?

```
1/a + 1/(a+b) + 1/(a+2b) + 1/(a+3b) + ... + 1/(a+k*b)
```

I'm looking for math optimization.

Thanks!

Comment: if k is a constant, yes. Otherwise, NO

Comment: k is a constant. Please advise how. Thanks.

Comment: if it's a constant then just write the formula as-is, you don't need to ask this question. Unless you need mathematical transformations then you should ask on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

1. Write it out in summation notation:

   [image]
2. Multiply both the numerator and denominator by `1/a`.

   [image]
3. Take the numerator's `1/a` and take it out of the summation, since it's a constant.

   [image]
4. Distribute the denominator's `1/a`

   [image]
5. Redefine, to make completely clear to the less-versed in math, `c=b/a`:

   [image]
6. And now you have a general form. This form equates, as @sawa similarly noted (but I personally haven't checked whether his form and mine equate), to

   [image]
7. Since we defined `c=b/a`, substituting that back gives

   [image]

and unfortunately that is the furthest we can go, unless you can guarantee that `a/b` will always be an integer, which, I doubt you can guarantee.

In answer, no, you're better off using a loop. And besides, I suspect you may be prematurely optimizing here; use a profiler like `gprof` to find out where the *real* bottlenecks are, rather than aiming to fix the "obvious" / attractive-to-solve ones.

<sup>Note by the way that I should have denoted a different variable, say, `i`, instead of my `k`, and instead used `k` in place of `n`, to keep consistent with your naming. (That is, your `k` is my `n`.) However I'm too lazy to go back and re-LaTeX all these formulas.</sup>

Comment: Thank you Andrew! I was wondering whether there's some math tricks here helping simplify the calculation. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

If you need something really optimized for symbolic math calculation try to refer to Wolfram Mathematica API or equivalent programs (I think there are not so many supporting symbolic calculation, optimized and with API support).

However, the difference is approximatively the same that passes between accessing data in ram (you can think that is fast) and accessing data in a database through a index. The second option can be thousand of times faster than the first. I've really tried using a Ado.net DataSet against a real MySQL database. The second can be really, really faster.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do the calculation, but asking [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bj+%3D+0%7D%5Ek+1+%2F+%28a+%2B+j+b%29) (as Revious suggests) returned the result:

[image: \sum_{j = 0}^k 1 / (a + j b)]

Comment: I don't think this is going to help as calculating values of the digamma function is going to be just as hard if not harder.

Comment: @Zeki Maybe you are right. But this is a step towards it, if the OP's question is answerable at all.

Comment: Is there some further information about a and b (e.g. integer valued)?
This might simplify the formula.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for replying! a and b are integers. There's no further information.